# Get data from google firebase's firestore, put into global object/array javascript, react

Tags: javascript

I am trying to read from firestore and push that data into a global variable. I am able to push however the array acts differently outside the function (I've attached a screenshot from the console showing the dif). For example I can call `data[0]` or `data[1]` inside the function just fine but outside it returns "*undefined*". Can anyone help with this?
This is for a react project, so if there is a way to do it using react hooks or something like that, I can implement no problem.

```js
let fbData = [];

const GetData = async () => {
    const q = query(collection(db, "surveys"), where("surveyComplete", "==", true));
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        fbData.push({
            [doc.data().surveyId]: {
                "name": doc.data().surveyName,
                "id": doc.data().surveyId
            }            
        });
    }, 
    function (error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
}
```

And yes I know the way I structure my data is weird, I'm planning on fixing it once I figure this issue out.

[image: image of console log outside function and inside function]

Comment: Well, it seems you are console logging the `fbData` array *somewhere* before it's mutated in `GetData`, and when you inspect it in the browser console you see it mutated and populated. This is browser behavior. What are you trying to accomplish with the above code?

Comment: I'm trying to pull questions and answers from my DB to create a form with said questions and answers. Your comment makes sense, when you say the first console log is logging ```fbData``` before it is mutated is correct (I checked with setInterval to log it in global scope after one second). I think I'll try using a promise, so it only populates the form inputs after the initial GetData function finishes.

Comment: Whatever it is that you are trying to update should probably be in some React state, if you are using React. Enqueue a state update with the values you want and it then triggers a rerender with the updated state. I think you're already starting off on the wrong foot in React if you're trying to use some global variable.

Comment: I originally tried that but when I would add a setState it would rerender and make an infinite loop. So from what I can see I need to set the firebase data to a global variable and then add it to state. But I'm trying different ways to use useEffect and setState there right now.

Comment: Yes, infinite render loops are caused by unconditionally enqueuing state updates. Can you share more of what you are trying to do? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example